# Adding new pages in Django from existing data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to simply add a new 'blog' page in Django, which should replicate the home page. The home page is working fine, and if I view the URLs for my app, it looks like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

In my understanding of Django, I could add a 'blog' page by adding the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('blog/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='blog'), #ADDED LINE
]
```

However going to my http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ page returns a 404 error. With Django debugging enabled, I get the following message:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ Raised
> by:   main_site_app.views.PostDetail

From what I can observe, there is nothing additional that the index page has that the blog doesn't. Is there a step I'm missing here that is preventing the /blog/ page from showing up?

**EDIT:**
views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

    class PostList(generic.ListView):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
        template_name = 'index_2.html'
    
    class PostListLimited(generic.ListView):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')[:2]
        template_name = 'index_2.html'
    
    class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

Comment: can you post your views

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü sure, done. views.py added to OP.